# ldirectord balancing internal traffic doesnt work

Tags: load-balancing, ldirectord

Here is my ldirectord.cf file

checktimeout=10
checkinterval=2
autoreload=no
logfile="local0"
quiescent=yes

virtual=192.168.1.4:7777
        real=192.168.1.52:7777 gate
        scheduler=wlc
        protocol=tcp
        checktype=on

I cannot connect from another internal ip (192.168.1.81) and actually establish a connection

The socket on 192.168.1.52 is working

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

i have try using masq as well and cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ldirectord problem per se, but rather a NAT problem, which ldirectord (or, rather, ipvs, which is the underlying mechanism which ldirectord configures) is merely the current victim of.

What's happening is that the destination address of the initial packet is getting changed, but the source address isn't.  That means that when the answer is sent back, it's being sent straight back to the address that made the request, with a source address of the "backend" machine that received the request.

This *sounds* good, but the problem is that the requestor isn't expecting a response from the backend machine, it's expecting one from the virtual IP, so when it gets a packet from the backend machine, it drops it, because it doesn't think it's relevant.